# Getting the value of a button from a php script and posting the value to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, radiobuttonlist

I have been working on this for days, I've Google'd and re-searched but I can't seem to find exactly what am looking for. I have a menu tab which is populated by a php script as follows:

```
<?php include 'db_connector.php';

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM os_scope");

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<button type='radio'>"."<li>"."<div class='title'>"."<a href='#myPanel' >".$row['name']."</a>"."</div>"."</li>"."</button>";

            }
  ?>
```

The output of the result is this:

```
Billing    
Custom
Customer
Product
```

When I select any one of them i.e Billing it opens the #mypanel

I would like for each time I select an item i.e Billing, the value "Billing" should be posted to the panel, where I can then use this value to query MySQL database. And the same for the remaining items.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `<button type='text'>`?

Comment: sorry it should be <button type='radio'>.

Comment: Button has no valid type like radio. See this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp Do you mean, `<input type="radio" name="something" value="somevalue" />` ?

Anyway, your HTML syntax is bad also.

Comment: This question is too vague. Please clarify what you are trying to do. I imagine the solution is ajax based, but you havent tagged javascript

Comment: `<button type='submit'>` sure, but not `text` nor `radio` - **input** types, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what I was looking for,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php include 'db_connector.php';

 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM os_scope");

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

 $row['name'];

echo "<input type='radio' name='os' value=".$row['name']." id='myRadio'>";


                }
?>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the radio button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementsByName('os');
        var rate_value;
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            if(x[i].checked){
                rate_value = x[i].value;
                break;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = rate_value;

    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `<button type='radio'>`

Use `<input type='radio' value='value'>`

Try this:

```
echo "<li><input type='radio' value='".$row['name']."' /><div class='title'><a href='#myPanel' >".$row['name']."</a></div></li>";
```

Also, there is no reason to do this all over the place: `"."` Just let the string be a string. That's what strings do best.

Comment: Whilst this is all true, it does not answer the question (which is too vague to answer as it stands). I have not downvoted but this should really be a comment

Comment: @Adelphia, thank you so much for the suggestions, I tried using the code you'v given me but my open is not opening, also I dont want to have them as input buttons, is there a way of just having them as button but still get the functionality that I want??? Again any suggestions is very valuable and thank you for your help.

Comment: @Annie You can use toggle buttons but there isn't a native HTML element for that. You'll have to use some JS. http://jsfiddle.net/davidelrizzo/DYJkG/